# Dialog.dismiss is not working inside in adapter class

Tags: android, android-studio, android-layout

In my code, `dialog.dismiss();` function not working but callback function working perfectly, `callback.onItemClicked(position);`

Please help me, I'm new in the android field!

The same code working fine in `activity`, but problems arrive in the `adapter class`.

**Adapter Class**

```
public class Adapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<Adapter.ViewHolder> {
    private final Context mContext;
    private final ArrayList<String> mData;
    AdapterCallback callback;
    Dialog dialog;


    public Adapter(Context mContext, ArrayList<String> mData, AdapterCallback callback) {
        this.mContext = mContext;
        this.mData = mData;
        this.callback = callback;
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        return new ViewHolder(LayoutInflater.from(mContext).inflate(R.layout.item, parent, false));
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull ViewHolder holder, int position) {

        if (Helper.readSharedPref(mContext, Constants.PREF_KEY_Sub).equalsIgnoreCase("notActive")) {
            if (!mData.get(position).equalsIgnoreCase("PENDING")) {
           alertSuccessShowDialog(mContext, position);
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return mData != null ? mData.size() : 0;
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemViewType(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    public interface AdapterCallback {
        void onItemClicked(int position);
    }

    public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        TextView tv_bank_name;


        public ViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            tv_bank_name = itemView.findViewById(R.id.tv_bank_name);
        }
    }


    private void alertSuccessShowDialog(Context context, int position) {
        dialog = new Dialog(context);
        dialog.setContentView(R.layout.enquiry_popup);
        dialog.getWindow().setLayout(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        dialog.getWindow().setBackgroundDrawableResource(android.R.color.transparent);
        dialog.getWindow().setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
        dialog.setCancelable(false);
        dialog.findViewById(R.id.iv_close_btn).setOnClickListener(v -> {
            dialog.dismiss();
            callback.onItemClicked(position);
        });

        dialog.show();
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nothing wrong with your dialog box method code, just change calling method like this with new context...

```
alertSuccessShowDialog(holder.itemView.getContext(), position);
```

Answer (score 0):

What @Dev4life said is right you have to call after create the dialog, and you should use AlertDialog instead of Dialog because of security reasons i believe. There is a brief statement in the Documentation about:
[Dialogs](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/dialogs)

> The Dialog class is the base class for dialogs, but you should avoid
> instantiating Dialog directly. Instead, use one of the following
> subclasses:
>
> AlertDialog A dialog that can show a title, up to three buttons, a
> list of selectable items, or a custom layout. DatePickerDialog or
> TimePickerDialog A dialog with a pre-defined UI that allows the user
> to select a date or time.

Here is my code dunno, but should work:

```
public class Adapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<Adapter.ViewHolder> {
    
    private final Context mContext;
    private final ArrayList<String> mData;
    AdapterCallback callback;
    
    AlertDialog dialog;
    Button btnClose;
    AlertDialog.Builder builder;

    public Adapter(Context mContext, ArrayList<String> mData, AdapterCallback callback) {
        this.mContext = mContext;
        this.mData = mData;
        this.callback = callback;
    }

    public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        
        TextView tv_bank_name;

        public ViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            tv_bank_name = itemView.findViewById(R.id.tv_bank_name);
        }
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        return new ViewHolder(LayoutInflater.from(mContext).inflate(R.layout.item, parent, false));
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull ViewHolder holder, int position) {

        if (Helper.readSharedPref(mContext, Constants.PREF_KEY_Sub).equalsIgnoreCase("notactive")) {
            if (!mData.get(position).equalsIgnoreCase("pending")) {
           alertSuccessShowDialog(position);
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return mData != null ? mData.size() : 0;
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemViewType(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    public interface AdapterCallback {
        void onItemClicked(int position);
    }

    private void alertSuccessShowDialog(int position) {
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(mContext).inflate(R.layout.enquiry_popup, null, false);
        btnClose = view.findViewById(R.id.iv_close_btn);

        builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(mContext);
        builder.setView(view);
        
        dialog = builder.create();
        dialog.getWindow().setBackgroundDrawableResource(android.R.color.transparent);
        btnClose.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                callback.onItemClicked(position);
                dialog.dismiss();
            }
        });
        dialog.show();
    }
}
```

This is my last bet, dunno know how to fix.
Create a class for your dialog and if needed pass the Context in the Constructor.

> Dialog Class:

```
public class DialogEnquiry extends DialogFragment {
        
        private AdapterCallback callback;
        private int position;

        public DialogEnquiry(AdapterCallback callback,int position){
            this.callback = callback;
            this.position = position;
        }

        @NonNull
        @Override
        public Dialog onCreateDialog(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            
            View view = LayoutInflater.from(requireContext()).inflate(R.layout.enquiry_popup, null);
            btnClose = view.findViewById(R.id.iv_close_btn);
            btnClose.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    callback.onItemClicked(position);
                    dismiss();
                }
            });

            return new AlertDialog.Builder(requireContext())
            .setView(view)
            .create();
        }

        @Override
        public void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        getDialog().getWindow().setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(Color.TRANSPARENT));
        }
    }
```

And inside of your Adapter, maybe you will need to pass the fragment manager in the adapter, but i dunno if this is right, i'm new in android:

new DialogEnquiry(callback, position).show(fragmentManager, "dialog");

This is my last attempt, i hope this can give you some insight.
Good Lucky!

Comment: It's working not in a proper way when I pressed the button not working but when I pressed 3 times then it works and dismisses the dialog.
please fix this issue...

Comment: I changed the code, try to change the global variable, instead of using Dialog dialog; change to AlertDialog dialog;

Comment: Sorry bro, Now its completely not working

Comment: Srry, I changed the button of location so the dialog was being created without the method.

Comment: If is not working! Say is it not showing... or just not showing properly, is it giving some error.

Answer (score -1):

You have to change your code. Because you can't dismiss the dialog before showing it. So change your code like this.

```
private void alertSuccessShowDialog(Context context, int position) {
        dialog = new Dialog(context);
        dialog.setContentView(R.layout.enquiry_popup);
        dialog.getWindow().setLayout(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        dialog.getWindow().setBackgroundDrawableResource(android.R.color.transparent);
        dialog.getWindow().setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
        dialog.setCancelable(false);
        dialog.show();
        
        dialog.findViewById(R.id.iv_close_btn).setOnClickListener(v -> {
            dialog.dismiss();
            callback.onItemClicked(position);
        });
}
```

Comment: Mine dismiss code work after showing a dialog box you wrong sorry buddy!